# Qmake DEFINES macro with parameter

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, qmake

I want to know how to define C++ preprocessor macro using qmake DEFINES variable. I have tried to do the following:

Project file

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += c++14 console

SOURCES += main.cpp

DEFINES  += "TEMPORARY_UNUSED(x)=\"(void)x;\""
DEFINES  += "BASE_CLASS_UNUSED(x)=\"(void)x;\""
```

Main.cpp file

```
int main() {
    int hello;
    TEMPORARY_UNUSED(hello)
    BASE_CLASS_UNUSED(hello)
}
```

But this resulted in following error: `[main.o] Error 2`. I have no idea how macro definition (very simple by the way) could cause errors in build process.

This is macro definitions using c++'s `#define`. They work just as I expected

```
#define TEMPORARY_UNUSED(x) (void)x;
#define BASE_CLASS_UNUSED(x) (void)x;
```

The question is: how do I define c++ preprocessor macro using qmake DEFINES and how my macro was able to cause compilation errors.

**P.S.** I'm perfectly aware of `Q_UNUSED` macro but I prefer to have a macro that indicates not only that the variable is unused but also *why* it is unused.

**P.S.** Code that I have posted is 100% of my project, there no more files that define/redefine anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the parentheses and the semicolon with backslashes:

```
DEFINES += TEMPORARY_UNUSED\\(x\\)=\\(void\\)x\\;
```

Otherwise the () and the ; in the -D compiler argument will be interpreted as parts of a more complex command.

Note that the `/D` option of MSVC does not support function-like macro definitions. To overcome this restriction, write your preprocessor directives into a header file and include it with the `/FI` compiler switch.

Comment: does not work with msvc, "The /D option doesn't support function-like macro definitions"    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions?view=msvc-170

Comment: I will edit my answer.  Thanks for the hint.